# Mac Mini shows incorrect boottime, sleeptime, and waketime

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini that is set to automatically restart every morning at 2am, and wake from sleep every morning at 5am.  Recently I've wondered if it has actually been doing these automated processes, so I began to investigate.

For some reason I can't fathom, the reported boottime, sleeptime, and waketimes all seem to be incorrect.

```
MacMini:~ user$ sysctl -a |grep kern.boottime
kern.boottime: { sec = 1571572834, usec = 480562 } Sun Oct 20 05:00:34 2019
MacMini:~ user$ sysctl -a |grep sleeptime
kern.sleeptime: { sec = 0, usec = 0 } Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
MacMini:~ user$ sysctl -a |grep waketime
kern.waketime: { sec = 0, usec = 0 } Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
```

I performed the above commands at 08:46am local time (Pacific).  The system claims to have rebooted at 5am, when it is set to reboot at 2am.  It is however set to wake at 5am, so I find this coincidence curious.  Additionally, if I go into System Information and look at Time since boot, it claims the machine last rebooted at about 5:40am.

Also, just before issuing the initial commands, I manually put the machine to sleep and woke it up.  Yet the sleep and waketimes are *both* listed as December 31 1969 at 16:00:00 exactly?

I haven't the faintest idea what's going on here so am hoping someone else can help shed some light.